# How do I hide the black bar on top?

Tags: interface

[image]

How do I hide the black bar on top?

ubuntu 21.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install [Hide Top Bar](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/545/hide-top-bar/) GNOME extension.